# Get email using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, imap, pop3

All I need is get email in PowerShell Script and see at its topic - with pop3 or imap, doesnt matter.
I tried to find solution, but all I found is either 3rd party .net assebmlies, or MS Exchange direct work. Both are not appropriate.
How to use SMTP and send email - its absolutely clear, but how to receive? Isn't there any standard assemblies similar to System.Net.Mail?

Comment: may want to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26606/free-pop3-net-library

Answer (score 7):

Here is a code I have been using on c#. I have Imported the dll to powershell and used it to retrieve different parts of a message. The dll I used is Imapx2 which is an open source. I understand that you don't want to use a third party .NET assemblies but this might help other people trying to reach to this content.

```
### Import the dll
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile(“YourDirectory\imapx.dll”)
### Create a client object
$client = New-Object ImapX.ImapClient
###set the fetching mode to retrieve the part of message you want to retrieve, 
###the less the better
$client.Behavior.MessageFetchMode = "Full"
$client.Host = "imap.gmail.com"
$client.Port = 993
$client.UseSsl = $true
$client.Connect()
$user = "User"
$password = "Password"
$client.Login($user,$password)
$messages = $client.Folders.Inbox.Search("ALL", $client.Behavior.MessageFetchMode, 1000)
foreach($m in $messages){
$m.Subject
foreach($r in $m.Attachments){
$r | Out-File "Directory"
    }
 }
```

I hope this was helpful

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

I used the suggestion of Falah Abu Hassan and it worked very well for my requirements for receiving mails via IMAP!

**How to get the IMAPX.DLL**

The Github Repository for imapx is found here:
https://github.com/azanov/imapx

Unfortunably you have to compile it yourself with "Visual Studio" to get the imapx.dll.

**Creation of an sample Powershell Script**

The Script and the DLL should be placed side and can integrated with this:

```
$path = Split-path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile(“$path\imapx.dll”)
```

The following example script, inspired by the answer from Falah Abu Hassan worked very well for me:

```
$path = Split-path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile(“$path\imapx.dll”)

### Create a client object
$client = New-Object ImapX.ImapClient

$client.Behavior.MessageFetchMode = "Full"
$client.Host = "Servername"
$client.Port = 993
$client.UseSsl = $true
$client.IsDebug = $true
$client.ValidateServerCertificate = $true
$client.Connect()

$user = "login@domain"
$pass = 'password'


$client.Login($user, $pass)

$messages = $client.Folders.Inbox.Search("ALL", $client.Behavior.MessageFetchMode, 100)

write-host "Count found: $($messages.count)"

foreach($m in $messages){
    write-host "Processing Subject: $($m.Subject)"
}
```