# Giving an automatic email reply based on reading the subject line

Tags: email, powershell, imap

I have been toying with this idea for few days now.
What I want to do is: I have a powershell script which sends mails mentioning status of some links which I am monitoring.
I wanted to add its functionality. I wanted to add a feature like, when a user sends the mail to a particular email ID with a subject line like "Status", it should send the user, the result of the powershell script.

From my perspective, an IMAP configuration needs to be done in the script. But just wanted opinion if this idea is feasible or not. I have IMAP configured in my organization. I just need to learn how to configure the script with IMAP settings so that the script can send automatic replies after reading the subject line.

IF this is possible from any other technology, then I would like to learn that as well.

**EDIT:** 
Its not a duplicate, because here I want to know pretty basic stuff, like if its possible, and if it is, then what are the technology I need to use to make it possible. Let me know your suggestions.

I saw the duplicate question as well; well it hasn't been properly answered and the links given don't work.

Please help me here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get email using PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959668/get-email-using-powershell)

Comment: Use `Send-MailMessage` for you reply, it's a piece of cake. what you need to worry is "get mail", it is not easy. if you use gmail, check this https://github.com/nikoblag/Gmail.ps

Comment: Hello Bum, I saw your script, its great.

I will try to implement it, see if it helps my cause.