# Import CSV from zipped Email Attachment to SQL Server

Tags: csv, sql-server-2008, ms-access, unzip, exchange-server-2013

Every day I receive an email from an external 3rd party which has data attached in a zipped CSV format.

What I want to do is automate the import of this data to a SQL server database. The email is not local to the server, so presumably I need to unzip and save the file to a folder somewhere the server can see it, then simply bulk insert it?

Is it possible to get exchange server to automate this saving and unzipping, or do I need to do it via another application? I have an access database running on a daily schedule which conceivably do this. The access database could also link to the SQL tables and perform the insert, but I don't know the relative merits and performance of doing so vs a bulk insert or SQL based alternative?

Comment: You might want to look at SSIS as a way of automating your unzip, save, and import process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had some time to work on this, and while it's not pretty I've got it working.

First I use outlook vba cobbled together from snippets on the web and here to save the attachments into a folder, and unzip them

Then I use the following in SQL to loop through the same folder and import the csv files.

```
CREATE TABLE #ALLFILENAMES(WHICHPATH VARCHAR(255),WHICHFILE varchar(255))

--some variables
declare @filename varchar(255),
        @path     varchar(255),
        @sql      varchar(8000),
        @cmd      varchar(1000)


--get the list of files to process:
SET @path = Full_UNC_Path
SET @cmd = 'dir ' + @path + '*.csv /b'
print @cmd
INSERT INTO  #ALLFILENAMES(WHICHFILE)
EXEC Master..xp_cmdShell @cmd
UPDATE #ALLFILENAMES SET WHICHPATH = @path where WHICHPATH is null


--cursor loop
declare c1 cursor for SELECT WHICHPATH,WHICHFILE FROM #ALLFILENAMES where WHICHFILE like '%.csv%'
open c1
fetch next from c1 into @path,@filename
While @@fetch_status <> -1
  begin

  --bulk insert won't take a variable name, so make a sql and execute it instead:
   set @sql = 'BULK INSERT tbl_MyInbound FROM ''' + @path + @filename + ''' '
       + '     WITH ( 
               FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', 
               ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'', 
               FIRSTROW = 2 
            ) '
print @sql
exec (@sql)

  fetch next from c1 into @path,@filename
  end
close c1
deallocate c1


--Extras

--delete from ALLFILENAMES where WHICHFILE is NULL
--select * from #ALLFILENAMES
drop table #ALLFILENAMES

if (@prevXpCmdshell = 0)
begin
exec sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0
reconfigure
end

if (@prevAdvancedOptions = 0)
begin
exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0
reconfigure
end
```

However, I'd like to delete the file as well, after importing it to prevent reimport etc. I tried the following but it didn't work, outputting `Access is denied`

```
set @cmd = 'del ' + @path + @filename
EXEC master..cp_cmdShell @cmd
```

If I can just figure out why I can't delete the file, then I would be a happy guy. Any ideas?

Comment: I believe that you would have to grant modify permissions for the folder to whichever service account is running the Outlook VBA script.

Answer (score 3):

That deeply depends on your environment (which SQL rights you have, which email server you have). So its not easy to answer that. What we do (via an Powershell script) is the following:

1.) We use a small self coded application which download the content from a mail server. As you didn´t specified your server there are different solutions possible:

- [Exchange WebServices](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/20156908-44f8-40b6-997d-563af2ed13df/download-email-attachements-with-powershell-from-exchange-server?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment)
- POP3 ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959668/get-email-using-powershell) or [here](https://www.cogmotive.com/blog/powershell-scripts/pop-mailbox-using-powershell))
- [IMAP](https://www.example-code.com/powershell/imap_unread.asp)

2.) The exported SQL file will be imported via:

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

*P.S.
Make sure that you only handle only the attachment where you know the name from e.g. SQLdumpABC.zip and not every *.zip. This is to prevent that you handle every malware send to your "solution" ;-)*